# Multiple UITableView Cell Types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to setup a tableview that will have 10 different cells that can be in any order, with any amount of each type. I have a very dynamic data source. Most of the cells will have dynamic heights, and also contain another UITableView or a UICollectionView. So there are nested views.

This all feels messy, since a TableViewCell is going to contain a TableView/CollectionView that has it's own cells. Data sources, and delegates get confusing fast.

Designing the cells in interface builder is also difficult, since there is very little space I can work with when configuring 10 different cell types.

So my question is, what would be the best way to setup so many different cell types in one table? Is it bad to have cells with TableViews / CollecitonViews inside of them?

Comment: No its a well practiced mthodology

Comment: use only CollecitonViews, you can make the same of tableviews with a collectionView that have 1 column